# ext js - can you put an combobox in a GridPanel ? (not an EditorGrid)

Tags: extjs

HI,
I have only seen documentation where you can put a combobox in an EditorGrid, but i am just looking for a simple solution, where my grid has a one column that is a comboBox, with basically a Yes/No option. I just want to be able to access the Yes/No value when i dblclick a particular grid row.
can this be done without using a EditorGrid Panel?.
if so, can point me to an example ? that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with some effort -- I don't have any code off hand for you, but plugging into the grid should be possible. I would suggest that if you need a boolean value, you should go with a checkbox instead of a combo.  It's lighter weight and simpler to implement as a plugin to the grid.  See the last example on [this page](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/grid-plugins.html) to see if that's something that might work for you.